# Should credit scores be encrypted?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I know obviously that credit card info should be encrypted, but should credit SCORES be encrypted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. First thing you must understand is the sensitivity of the data. Never expose an important data that is not encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

***Anything*** that is *sensitive and should be private*, **must** be kept encrypted. Only you know whether credit SCORES is sensitive and should be encrypted.

Comment: touché. i'll go ahead and just encrypt that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this as a right vs. wrong question. There is no rule anywhere about this. It's a policy decision to be made by the people directly involved.

That said, I would keep all customer information very secure. If that requires encrypting the data, then that's what should be done.

Answer (score 1):

Everything that is personal must be protected. Credit report is the record of all the loan/credit you have got. Also it contains many more information of a person. And credit report & [credit score](http://www.freecreditscore.com/) both are important, so must be encrypted.